# Query returning data even when statement is False in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

the problem i am facing is that my sql query is returning values even when the statement is false. following is attached my code:-

controller:-

```
public function seller_edit_profile()
{
    if($this->userlib->isLoggedIn())
    {
        if($this->userlib->isAdmin())
        {
            $id2 = $this->userlib->getId();
            $id['admin_data'] = $this->admin_panel_model->admin_data($id2);
            $id['data'] = $this->admin_panel_model->seller_edit_data();
            $this->load->view('seller_edit_data', $id);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "User not Authorised";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "User not Logged In";
    }
}
```

model:-

```
public function seller_edit_data()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                      ->from('seller_details')
                      ->join('seller', 'seller.id = seller_details.id')
                      ->join('bank_details', 'seller_details.id = bank_details.id' )
                      ->join('store_details', 'seller_details.id = store_details.id')
                      ->where(array('seller.admin_check'=>6, 'seller.isAdmin'=>0))
                      ->or_where(array('seller.admin_check'=>7, 'seller.isAdmin'=>0))
                      ->get();
    return $query->result();              
}
```

earlier,the data with admin_check = 7 is displayed,but when i change the status to admin_check = 0, it should not be seen in the view file "seller_edit_data" but yet its been shown here.

or for simple understanding,when i displayed $id['data'] i got values from database which ideally should not be there.

thanks in advance1

Comment: it is an `or` condition so even if `admin_check = 0`  it will work if all other conditions are true.

Comment: what is the recommended solution then? @TintuCRaju

Comment: yes it was,now the issue is resolved, thanx for the help @TintuCRaju

Comment: Good . I appreciate that you resolve it by yourself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$query= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM seller INNER JOIN seller_details ON 'seller.id=seller_details.id' INNER JOIN bank_details ON 'seller.id=bank_details.id' INNER JOIN store_details ON 'seller.id=store_details.id' where 'seller.admin_check' = 6 OR 'seller.admin_check' = 7 ");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Use `result_array` to when you return data to controller

Comment: @AjitejKaushik check this

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved, there was problem with query,i have worked it out myself.
replacing the query in the model with

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM seller INNER JOIN seller_details ON 'seller.id=seller_details.id' INNER JOIN bank_details ON 'seller.id=bank_details.id' INNER JOIN store_details ON 'seller.id=store_details.id' where 'seller.admin_check' = 6 OR 'seller.admin_check' = 7 ");
```

and its displaying the correct result.